# SSRS Integration

Tags: integration

I have requirements to push a Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services report through to a SalesForce instance.
I can't seem to find any guides, and while I know that SSRS reports can be embedded in custom webpages, I'm not sure if I can further embed such a solution in SalesForce? What steps and setup or programming would be required?
Does anyone have experience with this and a solution to publishing SSRS reports in SalesForce?
Thanks!

Edit: Since there's no SQL, SQL Server, SSRS, or Microsoft tags this may be a long shot...

Comment: Do you need to pass any data from Salesforce to SSRS, or just embed the page in the Salesforce UI?

Answer (score 2):

This might be a cheap answer, but just to check you have read this

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/platform_connectpre/canvas_framework.pdf